# get started Starling with Flash Professional cs5 but i've got error when adding Staring variable

Tags: flash-cs5, starling-framework

I've tried below but I can't even make Starling variable.

1) already followed and set this: http://blogs.adobe.com/rgalvan/2011/11/adding-fp11-support-to-flash-pro-cs5-and-cs5-5.html

2) downloaded starling.swc from starling sample

3) Make HelloStl.fla file by creating new ActionScript 3.0 using Flash Professional CS5

4) Add starling.swc on library path

5) Write "HelloStarling" on fla properties's Class and Edit This like below

```
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import starling.core.Starling;

public class HelloStarling extends MovieClip {

private var st:Starling;
public function HelloStarling() {
 // constructor code
trace("check");
}
```

6) Execute this. Control -> Test Movie -> Test

But I've got errors like below,

```
VerifyError: Error #1079: native methods are not allowed in loaded code
ReferenceError: Error #1065: variable HelloStarling is not defined
```

I think "private var:st:Starling" this line caused above error. And "check" also doesn't printed

Is there anybody know about this error?
Please help..

Answer (score 0):

What the .. !!

Self Answer.

I installed CS6 instead of CS5.

After that, Everything gonna OK!

I think, The Error caused from FP11 setting!! :<

I recommend just use CS6 not CS5!!!!